# while running SP in Oracle particular column has value but in C# it is coming blank

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a SP in Oracle which is executing fine when passing the parameters:

```
OPEN cur FOR WITH TmpResultCTE AS
        (
            SELECT  X.Month,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MID DESC) AS Row_Num,
                    X.MID,
                    X.ProcessorName,
                    X.TotalTransactionAmount,
                    to_number(to_number(X.Fixed)+  to_number(X.MDR) + to_number(X.Rental)+ to_number(X.TransactionFee)+ to_number(X.Others)) AS Fees,                   
                    X.MDR,
                    X.TransactionFee,
                    X.ServiceTax,
                    X.Fixed,
                    X.Rental, 
                    X.Others,
                    X.BusinessName 

            FROM
            (
              SELECT    p_Month as  Month,
                        V.MID,
                        'Bank switch' AS ProcessorName,
                        SUM(NVL(U.Total_Amount,0)) AS TotalTransactionAmount,
                        SUM(NVL(U.MDR,0)) AS MDR,
                        SUM(NVL(U.TransactionFee,0)) AS TransactionFee,
                        SUM(NVL(U.ServiceTax,0)) AS ServiceTax,
                        NVL((SELECT T."LineItem_Data" FROM TEMPSTLMNTMIDCOLECTION1 T WHERE T.MID=V.MID AND T."LineItem_Name"='Monthly Fee'),0) as Fixed,
                        NVL((SELECT T."LineItem_Data" FROM TEMPSTLMNTMIDCOLECTION1 T WHERE T.MID=V.MID AND T."LineItem_Name"='Rental'),0) as Rental, 
                        NVL((SELECT T."LineItem_Data" FROM TEMPSTLMNTMIDCOLECTION1 T WHERE T.MID=V.MID AND T."LineItem_Name"='Others'),0) as Others,        
                        (SELECT trim(TC.BusinessName) FROM TEMPSTLMNTMIDCOLECTION TC WHERE TC.MID=V.MID) as BusinessName        
              FROM      UPI_MRCH_SETTLEMENT_DATA U INNER JOIN  MerchantVpa_MBA V ON U.Payee_Vpa=V.VPA
                        WHERE TO_CHAR(Transaction_Date, 'Month') LIKE '%'||p_Month||'%' AND TO_CHAR(Transaction_Date, 'YYYY') = v_Year
                        GROUP BY V.MID
            ) X
        )
        --[dbo].[PROC_SETTLEMENT_FEES 'May','',1,1000
        --OPEN cur5 FOR SELECT-1) FROM dual; * FROM TmpResultCTE WHERE RowNum > v_FirstRec AND RowNum < v_LAStRec
        SELECT * FROM TmpResultCTE WHERE Row_Num > v_FirstRec AND Row_Num < v_LAStRec and rownum<v_LAStRec;
```

Below screen shot it the output:
[image: ORACLE OUTPUT]

But in C# it is coming Blank:

below is c# output:
[image: C# Output]

Kindly help not getting the issue.

For clarification I am showing c# output in 2 different pic:
[C# output 1[image: -2]

Answer (score 0):

> "But in C# it is coming Blank:"

Actually not quite true. While you have made it hard for us by posting screenshots with teeny fonts we can see that the C# result set appears to have the same rows as the database result set. The difference is that some *cells* are zero or blank in the C# output.

If we look at the query, we see that the columns which exhibit these differences are the ones which come from `TEMPSTLMNTMIDCOLECTION1`. So, what is `TEMPSTLMNTMIDCOLECTION1`? How is it populated? Is it a temporary table or PL/SQL collection? If so, is the session which which is executing the query in C# the same session which populates the structure?

---

> "I mean all columns has value there but in c# the value of business name is blank"

Are you sure? There are some other columns which have non-zero values in database output which are zero in C# output (assuming the row order is the same: your screen shots obfuscate the IDs so it's hard to be certain).

Because it is more likely that you are not populating the table properly than that your are populating the table and some part of the result set goes missing in the C# call.

Comment: Hi, ya same session actually rest of the column is coming ok but one with business name is not coming and TEMPSTLMNTMIDCOLECTION1 is the temp table which has all the values except Business name TEMPSTLMNTMIDCOLECTION is the the table which is having BusinessName and it is showing in Oracle correctly, I mean all columns has value there but in c# the value of business name is blank

Comment: Then you should edit your question to say exactly what the problem is.